# How do I get Recoll to open a parent directory using Thunar instead of Dolphin?

Tags: recoll

When I right click on a search result and choose "Open Parent document/folder", the folder opens in Dolphin. I would prefer to use Thunar, as I run XFCE on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question to document my findings).

In Preferences > GUI configuration > User interface > Choose editor applications, change the command of "inode/directory|parentopen" to "thunar %f".